# Tridion Deployer Unable to store item in current transaction

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, deployer

In our **Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1** environment, when publishing out a Category we're getting a failure while the deployer is attempting to Commit the Deployment, and are seeing an error in the logs of:

> ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to start processing deployment package with >transactionId: tcm:0-103170-66560
>   com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase >failed. Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-103170-66560. Unable to store item >inside current transaction

Any ideas where this transaction setting could be that we could expand? It doesn't appear to be an environment timeout, as it can at times fail in as few as a couple of seconds.

If it helps, this is using a SQL Server instance to store the Category/Keywords, and we have already applied hotfix CD_2013.1.1.1419

Continued Error Stack here:

> ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to start processing deployment package with transactionId: tcm:0-103388-66560
>   com.tridion.deployer.
>
> ProcessingException: Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed.
>
> Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-103388-66560. Unable to store item inside current transaction
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:209) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:100) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
>
> Caused by: com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-103388-66560
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.handleFailure(PreCommitPhase.java:131) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.execute(PreCommitPhase.java:109) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:198) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       ... 9 common frames omitted
>
> Caused by: com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to store item inside current transaction
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.runPrepare(PreCommitPhase.java:161) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.execute(PreCommitPhase.java:101) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       ... 10 common frames omitted

Comment: In case the below hotfix as sugested by Hiren also does not work, share the storage type section of your cd_storage_config.xml - This issue might also occur in case the syntax of database storage type is incorrect

Comment: Is this just failing for publishing category? If so, then your deployer is setup correctly, and this issue could be caused by a corruption in the content or even a duplicate entry. Try deleting the record in the broker and publish again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the root of the problem, turned out to be due to the character limit on the keyword metadata in the Broker Database.

KEY_STRING_VALUE field in the CUSTOM_META table is defined as VARCHAR2 which has the 4000 byte restriction, and one of our keywords had an excessive amount of characters.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the error it seems like database timeout issue where commit did not happen within time.

> You have tagged your question with 2013, are you on 2013 or 2013 sp1
>   or 2013 sp1 hr1?

If you are 2013 sp1 hr1, there is one hotfix **CD_2013.1.1.1419_tcm89-21665** that you should apply.

If you are on any other version other than 2013 sp1 hr1 then:
Short term: you can work with DBA to perform profiling on broker database and check if any timeout is happening.
Long term: upgrade to 2013 sp1 hr1 and apply the mentioned hotfix. If still issue persists then raise support ticket.

Comment: You can probably apply the hotfix much faster than having the DBA to profile, troubleshoot and perform an analysis. Hotfix should be the immediate fix rather than the long term fix. Additionally, you can also enable hibernate logging on the logback.xml to get more detailed error

Comment: Updated description, we are using 2013 sp1 hr1, and have also applied the hotfix you mentioned.